# What does ゴリってる mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

I assume it's some slang that comes from ゴリラ perhaps. I found many examples of it being used in completely different situations and now I'm very confused... Apparently there is even a [small book](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E4%BC%9A%E8%A9%B1%E9%9B%86-%E6%96%B9%E6%89%8B%E9%9B%85%E5%A1%9A-ebook/dp/B0162961OQ) about its meaning, haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the author of ゴリってる会話集 [doesn't know the meaning of ゴリる](https://katatemasatsuka.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%80%8C%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8A%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%81%A6%E3%80%81%E3%80%8C%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D/). He just used it as a meaningless word which just sounds odd.

> 西川氏：　ほとんど意味不明ですが、何となくストーリーはわかるのが不思議ですね。
>   おっさん：　そうやがな。そこが面白いんや。はっきり言うて、「ゴリってる」の意味などさっぱりわからん。しかし、文脈によってその意味は何となくわかるんや。その不思議な言葉を駆使して、ストーリーが展開していくんや。

So this book only proves that ゴリる is not an established word :-)

---

That said, ゴリる is a possible word made up from ゴリラ using [this rule](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24351/5010). It would mean "be like a gorilla", "do something like a gorilla", etc. You may find ゴリる in rhythm game contexts because ゴリラ is slang for [an incredibly skillful player](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A9%E4%BA%BA%E9%96%93).

Someone might use it as short for [ごり押し](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E6%8A%BC%E3%81%97)する or [ゴリゴリ](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA)している, too.

Comment: So ゴリってる = _gorilling_?  :)  "It's a _gorilling_ story!"  That kinda works, since it almost sounds like _thrilling_ -- and it's also nonsense in English, much like [that author's use of ゴリる](https://katatemasatsuka.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%80%8C%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8A%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%81%A6%E3%80%81%E3%80%8C%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D/).

Comment: Exactly, it's *gorilling*!