# Can you form verbs from 擬態語 or 擬音語 by adding -る?

Tags: grammar, verbs, onomatopoeia

I know that you can form a verb from 擬態語 or 擬音語 by adding する after them, but in this sentence it appears the writer used -る instead.

> 会場に向かう前に**もじゃった**髪の毛をどうにかしようと行きつけの美容院に行ったんです。

Is it something common? Or just something weird that the writer did here? Thank you for your help!

Comment: To my mind もじゃる is one of the commoner, or at least more easily-understandable products of verb-forming process of this kind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it's definitely slangy but somewhat common. Other examples include:

- [ピヨる](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%94%E3%83%A8%E3%82%8B) from ピヨピヨ, to be stunned (by a strong attack)
- [もにょる](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AB%E3%82%87%E3%82%8B) from もにょもにょ, to mumble, not to know what to say, etc.
- [ボコる](http://zokugo-dict.com/30ho/bokoru.htm) from ボコボコ, to beat (someone)

This type of verb formation is relatively common [with foreign words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24351/5010), but it's not limited to them. You may sometimes see verbs formed even from a person name, for example [マミる](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%9F%E3%82%8B).

Perhaps this kind of new verbs are playfully coined by native speakers almost every day, but few will come into general use. AFAIK もじゃる is not common.

Comment: According to the link and other resources, もにょる seems to have a different meaning than *mumble*. :)

Comment: @goldbrick ちょっとつけたしました