# 湿気る is both godan and ichidan. Are there other verbs like this?

Tags: verbs, godan-verbs, ichidan-verbs

I recently noticed in passing that 湿気る is classified as both a godan and an ichidan verb.
For example, the past tense could be either:

しけった (godan)

or

しけた　 (ichidan).

This strikes me as being fairly unusual. Offhand, I can't think of any other verbs that have this feature. Perhaps someone knows other verbs which are classified as both godan and ichidan? Maybe someone even knows why...

Comment: `しけった` -- ん？　「しけた」「しっけた」って言うけど。。　「しける」「しっける」やし。。あれ？私だけ？

Comment: The dictionary has 3 forms. https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%B9%BF%E6%B0%97%E3%82%8B

Comment: @Chocolate ah you're correct I think. I will edit that.

Comment: Now with the edit you have the two ichidan forms represented, but not the 3rd godan form. I think Chocolate is just saying that people don't say the godan version much.

Comment: @Leebo wow 3 forms. So しけた、しっけた, and しけった are somehow all correct? That's quite bizarre.

Comment: @Leebo ah I see.

Comment: @Leebo 「しっけてる」「しけってる」両方とも聞くような気がします・・

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not an optimal method, but I did a full text search on デジタル大辞泉 with `五段化`, and found the following examples of ichidan-to-godan change.

- 湿気る: 下一段動詞「しけ（湿気）る」の五段化。
- 下さる: 《動詞「くだされる」（下一）の五段化》
- 抉る: 《「こじる」（上一）の五段化》
- 遣わさる: ［動ラ五（四）］「つかわされる」（下一段）の五段化。

下さる and 抉る are always godan in modern Japanese. I didn't know 遣わさ(れ)る can conjugate as a godan verb. I did a similar search on 明鏡国語辞典 and 湿気る was the only verb with the remark "五段にも活用". So I think 湿気る is a rare example of verbs that are both fully godan and fully ichidan in modern Japanese.

FWIW, I think I usually use the godan version of 湿気る. Most similar slangy verbs made from an on-yomi noun usually conjugate as a godan verb (駄弁る, 事故る, 愚痴る, ...), so the ichidan version may become less popular in the far future. [This question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52536/5010) may be related.

Comment: 五段「しける」が「しけらない、しけります、しける、しければ、しけった」、下一段「しける」が「しけない、しけます、しける、しければ、しけた」、下一段「しっける」が「しっけない、しっけます、しっける、しっければ、しっけた」← あってます？ 　あれ？「しっけらない、しっけります」ってのもあります？　おかしい？

Comment: 「しっける」は、聞いたことは間違いなくありますけど辞書に載ってないですね。「しっけない、しっけて（一段）」ではなく「しっけらない、しっけって（五段）」と活用させる人がいても全然不思議ではないと思いますがよく分かりません。「しけった煎餅」と「しけた煎餅」は個人的にはどっちもアリです。