# Is 結晶 a verb and a noun?

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech

I've seen it being used as a noun for 'crystals' in a game and it's also been used as a verb in the form of 'Kesshou!(crystallize!)' for a superhero transformation call in Spielban.

Is simply saying Kesshou normal for using it as a verb or do you normally attach -suru to make Kesshou a verb?

Comment: "Crystal" and "crystallization" are both nouns in English. Did you mean "crystallize"?

Comment: スピルバンが言う「結晶」って、仮面ライダーが言う「変身！」みたいなものですか？

Comment: Chocolate I guess yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you thinking if one might say けっしょいます, けっしょって or something like that? Then definitely no, 結晶 itself is a simple noun that never conjugates. (A crystal maniac might try coining such a verb [using this pattern](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24351/5010) as a joke, but I have never heard such a verb.) 結晶する is still ungrammatical. If you want
to say "to crystallize", it's 結晶**化**する (works transitively and intransitively), where 化 (か) is a suffix like *-ization*.

"結晶化!" is too long as a "transformation call", so 結晶 is a reasonable choice for that. Just because it's used similarly to "変身!" does not mean it's a verb. Shouting a pure noun is not strange even in English (e.g., "Attention!", "Silence!")

Comment: I see so it's a show thing but not necessarily grammatical. 変身する actually is grammatical from what I've remembered hearing though...

Comment: @shoryuu Calling this ungrammatical is like calling "Attention!" ungrammatical...

Comment: Another example: At the beginning of class, the class representative (学級委員) says 「起立・礼・着席」.

Comment: `結晶する is still ungrammatical` -- ところがですね・・　明鏡は、「結晶」を〘名・自サ変〙って書いてて、「二酸化珪素が結晶して水晶になる」って例文が・・[デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/68336/meaning/m0u/結晶/)も、「［名］(スル)」って書いてて、「日々の努力が結晶する」って例文が。。。