# Pronunciation Troubles with トラブル and トラブる: Loanwords with both noun and verb ending in ru mora

Tags: pronunciation, pitch-accent

Following [this comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24351/what-are-the-principles-behind-turning-foreign-language-words-into-verbse-g-%E3%82%B0?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment53167_24352):

What is the difference in pronunciation or pitch accent between:

- トラブル and トラブる
- ダブル and ダブる

What are the regional differences (if any)?

Is the pronunciation rule generalisable to other pairs of the form ＊＊ル and ＊＊る?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[トラブル]{LHLL} -- [トラブる]{LHHL}

[ダブル]{HLL} -- [ダブる]{LHL}

[バトル]{HLL} -- [バトる]{LHL}?

(I can't think of any other pairs...)

The verbs seem to have a pronunciation rule:

[サボる]{LHL}、 [テンパる]{LHHL}、 [ハモる]{LHL}、 [パニクる]{LHHL}、 [バグる]{LHL}、 [ググる]{LHL}、 [スタンバる]{LHHHL} ...

But I can't find a rule for loanwords ending with ル...

[トラブル]{LHLL}、 [サンダル]{LHHH}、 [ライフル]{HLLL}、 [バトル]{HLL}、 [メタル]{LHH} / [メタル]{HLL}、[メダル]{LHH}...

<sub>As for the regional differences: In Kansai, for example, we pronounce these verbs like: [サボる]{HHH}、[テンパる]{HHHH}、[ハモる]{HHH}、[パニクる]{HHHH}、[バグる]{HHH}...</sub>

Comment: メタル{HLL}ですか？それとも メダル{LHH}…

Comment: え、[メタル]{LHH}って言うで・・ 　[ヘビーメタル]{LHHHLL}やけどね・・　[この辞書](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB)も［0］って書いてるしぃ・・ えっもしかして近年変わってきてるやつ？　[ドラマ]{HLL} → [ドラマ]{LHH}みたいに・・？

Comment: ！ それはびっくりです。ずっと メタル{HLL}だと思ってました。一応調べてみます…

Comment: NHKは メタル{LHH}だけでした（新辞典は見れなかったので旧です）が、新明解のは メタル{HLL}もあったので一安心です（笑）

Comment: この件ですが、NHKのアクセント**新**辞典の方を見てみたら メタル{HLL}が第1アクセントに変わっていました。時代の変化ですね…

Comment: 近年変わったってこと・・・？うええ・・ またまたジェネレーションギャップ・・・？