# パドル -What does it actually mean?

Tags: meaning, loanwords, onomatopoeia

I believe, many of you have already seen this meme.

In short, in a *PlayStation* game *Fate/Extra* an anime girl is singing *Jingle bells*-like song in Japanese:

> 走{はし}れ艝{そり}よ
>   風{かぜ}のように
>   月{ずき}見晴{みは}らを
>   **パドルパドル！**

Source: [Full original scene recording on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pedbysDKUQQ)

I just started to wonder, **what does it exactly mean?**

[Jisho considers it as a paddle](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%83%91%E3%83%89%E3%83%AB)

> A paddle is a tool used for pushing against liquids, either as a form of propulsion in a boat or as an implement for mixing.

[Among other meanings](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%89%E3%83%AB_(%E6%9B%96%E6%98%A7%E3%81%95%E5%9B%9E%E9%81%BF)), Japanese Wikipedia also considers it as a paddle or something similar. At the *Trivia* section [(here)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E3%83%91%E3%83%89%E3%83%AB), I have found that it can also mean some kind of punishment enforced in navy or former schools.

Is it a kind of onomatopoeia with a meaning similar to *Jingle bells*? Or maybe it stands for some kind of whip given to bad behaved children or something similar?

Comment: Related on Anime.SE: https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/43895/2516

Answer (score 3):

This song is basically a parody of [a Japanese translated version of *Jingle Bells*](http://www.utamap.com/showkasi.php?surl=F05608); the original line is 雪の中を軽くはやく, not 月海原をパドルパドル. Looks like even Japanese Fate fans do not understand what this パドル means (see [this](http://xn---fate-grandorder-794ovb07b7ht176ef78bjy3dxb0g.com/article/460847887.html) and [this](https://twitter.com/search?q=%E3%83%91%E3%83%89%E3%83%AB%E3%83%91%E3%83%89%E3%83%AB%20%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3&src=typed_query&f=live) for example), but most people seem to guess it is related to English "paddle" (either as a simple noun パドル or a [verb form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/24352/5010) パドる). A few people have noticed this English word is sometimes associated with a kind of punishment, but almost no Japanese people know such a fact, so I doubt this is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Paddle paddle. Probably referring to [hagoita](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSjRfrHfcWQ) used in [hanetsuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanetsuki) (Japanese badminton), a traditional Japanese New Year's game often played by girls.

And/or staying with the movement theme as in [wading through Tsukimihara U](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/56254/4248).