# Help understanding this phrase ヘマッたことが多すぎて?

Tags: meaning

From this manga panel:

[image]

I'm having trouble with understanding「ヘマッたことが多すぎて」

I guess this to be  "The messed up things (I did) are too many"

I think ヘマ = blunder, and こと = generic "thing", but I don't understand the ッた between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the past form of a slangy godan verb ヘマる.

e.g. やる → やった Likewise, へまる → へまった

Comment: Would there be a good resource to look up other slangy verbs I might find in manga?  Because I'm not able to find this in my usual JE dictionaries.

Comment: @Dani It would be good for you to understand how the verb was made, because you’ll come across new verbs made in a similar fashion that won’t be in your dictionary either.

Comment: @snailplane From this answer, my guess is it's just adding る to a noun like ヘマ.

Comment: @Dani Yep, that’s it! :-) Well, there’s a little more to it, but that’s essentially correct: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/24352/1478